# Errors in C# for unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

bool canJump;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("left"))
        {
            gameObject.transform.Translate(-50f * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            gameObject.transform.Translate(50f * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        ManageJump();
    }

    void ManageJump()
    {
        if(gameObject.transform.position.y <= 0)
        {
            canJump = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("up") && canJump && gameObject.transform.position.y < 10)
        {
            gameObject.transform.Translate(0, 50f * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }

        else
        {
            canJump = false;

            if (gameObject.transform.position.y > 0)
            {
                gameObject.transform.Translate(0, -50f * Time.deltaTime, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

I dont find the error in the code.

I get the following errors:

Assets\scripts\PlayerController.cs(35,13): error CS8801: Cannot use local variable or local function 'canJump' declared in a top-level statement in this context.

Assets\scripts\PlayerController.cs(38,35): error CS8801: Cannot use local variable or local function 'canJump' declared in a top-level statement in this context.

Assets\scripts\PlayerController.cs(45,13): error CS8801: Cannot use local variable or local function 'canJump' declared in a top-level statement in this context.

Assets\scripts\PlayerController.cs(38,35): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'canJump'

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Answer (score 2):

your variable is in the wrong location

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // this needs to go here
    bool canJump;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("left"))
        {
            gameObject.transform.Translate(-50f * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            gameObject.transform.Translate(50f * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        ManageJump();
    }

    void ManageJump()
    {
        if(gameObject.transform.position.y <= 0)
        {
            canJump = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("up") && canJump && gameObject.transform.position.y < 10)
        {
            gameObject.transform.Translate(0, 50f * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }

        else
        {
            canJump = false;

            if (gameObject.transform.position.y > 0)
            {
                gameObject.transform.Translate(0, -50f * Time.deltaTime, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, i just saw it... thanks